# What are the extremum points on this graph?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

[The graph in question is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39zvk.png)

> Assuming the inspected interval is $[0, 4]$:
>
> 1- The point $(0, 4)$ does not qualify to be an absolute maximum, but what about say $(0.000\cdots001, 3.9999\cdots)$? Why can't we say that the interval $[0, 4]$ has an absolute maximum even though there are relatively bigger values between $x = 0$ and $x = \frac13$?
>
> 2- Can we say that the point $(0, 1)$ is an absolute minimum for this interval?
>
> 3- The point $(1, 3)$ is a local maximum, right?
>
> 4- Lastly, what about the point $(4, 3)$? Can we say it's a local maximum too?

My thoughts are:
Questions 2 and 3 can most likely be answered with "yes". I've seen many conflicting answers regarding question 4, so I'm not sure anymore...

And question 1 is the one on which I couldn't find any relatable answers. The endpoint x = 0 where the function would normally have a maximum is not continuous. Therefore, appointing the "next closest" maximum value $(3.999\cdots)$ seemed logical enough, but apparently it doesn't work that way. But why is that? My guess would be that we can't define it as an **exact** point, therefore we dismiss it..? I would love some clarification on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no such point. For any point in the interval that you claim to be an absolute maximum, I can produce a point at which the graph is higher.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. Yes.

> Therefore, appointing the "next closest" maximum value $(3.999⋯)$ seemed logical enough, but apparently it doesn't work that way. But why is that?

There is no "next closest" point: for any non-zero $x$, there is some point between $0$ and $x$ (indeed, there are uncountably infinitely many such points). $3.999\ldots$ is exactly equal to $4$.